# Can I use JQuery Slidshow in my Commercial Project

Tags: jquery

I would like to use http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/ this jquery gallery in my commercial project. It is under MIT licence, I already searched about this licence on net but am still confusing whether we can use this or not... anyone please help me out... thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to read this license? It's just three short paragraphs and answer to your question is provided in the first.

Answer (score 2):

The [MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html) allows you to use it in a commercial project. This is one of the most permissive type of licenses.